# Delay on 12v sort of debouncing circuit?

Tags: delay, debounce

OK - - i have an opto sensor that runs on 12v (5-30 actually) and that is power by a battery/charge regulator/ 19v power supply and is used for counting how many times somebody goes past it on a site entrance ... HOWEVER .. the counter is sensitive ... and between the opto sensor and the counter you could flap your hand in fromt of it and count upto 20 in a heart beat ... SO  .. id like to limit the amount of inputs the counter receives to 1 every couple of seconds .. even a minute would do ... the pin on the counter ( an 7111hv ) just takes a high input ... the opto sensor (baumer i think) outputs an 11v high on one of its wires when the beam is broken ... but its all fairly low current and im trying not to use relays as i, trying to put the new circuit somewhere on the cable that supplies the opto sensor and id like to keep it from drawing too much current ... anyway ... the opto sensor has 3 wires ... 12v pos and neg plus signal wire ... so in my mind i need a delay on circuit that effectively 'debounces' multiple inputs into one single high so that the counter just sees one 11v signal of whatever length so that it just registers 1 not 2 million :) ... any thoughts ?

Comment: Welcome, to EE.SE. Sorry, maybe English is not your first language but your post is not intelligible. Can you reformat using proper sentences, capitalisation and punctuation?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a reverse engineering, modification and/or repair question. Please be aware that this type of question must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. More information can be found [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a RC filter.  [example circuit](https://learn.digilentinc.com/Documents/258)